# WPF When Binding to ContextMenu.IsOpen Context Menu flashes in top left corner of screen on first invocation

Tags: c#, wpf, contextmenu

I have already solved this problem, but the solution is counter intuitive in my opinion, so I'm making this post for others who run into this.

Below is a View model with the property `ShouldShow` this will bind to the context menu in the view:

```
public class VMMain : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool shouldShow;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public bool ShouldShow
    {
        get { return shouldShow; }
        set
        {
            shouldShow = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(ShouldShow)));
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="TestContextMenuBug.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestContextMenuBug"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Grid Background="Transparent">
        <Grid.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu IsOpen="{Binding ShouldShow}">
                <MenuItem Header="Menu Item" />
            </ContextMenu>
        </Grid.ContextMenu>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

When you right click in this window for the first time, the context menu will briefly flash in the top left corner of the screen. All subsequent clicks work properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thankfully the solution to this problem is easy.

`private bool shouldShow = true;`

Initializing the backing variable to `true` fixes this.  The solution to me is counter intuitive though, my context menu is not open initially, so why initialize the property that is binding to `IsOpen` to `true`?